# Creating link for dynamic content

Tags: flutter

I have a web page with a list of itens that are retrived from a database. The list is created and saved by a user.

I want to change the URL so a user can share a link with another and get the same list, but I have no clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) ([flutter-go-router](/questions/tagged/flutter-go-router)) package which supports "dynamic links".

Here is an example that displays the ID of a given URL:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _router = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      // initial route is '/'
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // this pushes to a new page - in this case, the 'simple' route
                  // with the id parameter set to 123
                  context.go('/simple/123');
                },
                child: Text('Go to Simple Screen'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: 'simple',
        path: '/simple/:id', // the :id is a path parameter and is dynamic
        builder: (context, state) {
          final id = state.pathParameters['id'] ?? 'No ID';
          return MyScreen(id: id);
        },
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: _router.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: _router.routeInformationParser,
      routeInformationProvider: _router.routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}

class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;

  const MyScreen({Key? key, required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Simple Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('ID: $id'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which results in:

[image]